# How to automatically collect analytics events for button click in android?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have to implement **Automatic Event Tracking** in android

Need to automatically collect analytics data on all button clicks and page views but it has to be done in a generic way so that I don't need to write the Analytics code again for every click.

Example: I have 2 buttons on my activity each of them having a click listener. Now i want to call Analytics.track(String buttonName) so that i do not have to add this in every click listener. The data that should be passed in tracking is button Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way (probably not the ultimate way) to do that could be extending `Button` (or `View`), and putting analytics code into the `View#performClick()` method.

As for the `buttonName`, it can be a a field of your custom View class, that you can set programmatically or even via an XML custom attribute.

**Global implementation :**

- Create a custom XML attribut : create a file named `attrs.xml` in the ressource folder :

  ```
  <resources>
      <declare-styleable name="tracking">
          <attr name="tracking_name" format="string" />
      </declare-styleable>
  </resources>
  ```
- Create a custom `Button` (or `View`) class, that overwrite `performClick()` method and call `Analytics.track()` with the string gotten from your XML custom attribute or set programmatically :

  ```
  public class TrackedClickButton extends Button {

      private String mTrackingName;

      public TrackedClickButton(Context context) {
          super(context);
      }

      public TrackedClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          init(context, attrs);
      }

      public TrackedClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
          init(context, attrs);
      }

      @TargetApi(21)
      public TrackedClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
          init(context, attrs);
      }

      private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.tracking);

          if (array.hasValue(R.styleable.tracking_name)) {
              mTrackingName = array.getString(R.styleable.tracking_name);
          }
      }

      public void setTrackingName(String trackingName) {
          this.mTrackingName = trackingName;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean performClick() {
          //Make sure the view has an onClickListener that listened the click event,
          //so that we don't report click on passive elements
          boolean clickHasBeenPerformed = super.performClick();
          if(clickHasBeenPerformed && mTrackingName != null) {
              Analytics.track(mTrackingName);
          }
          return clickHasBeenPerformed;
      }
  }
  ```
- Use your new class everywhere you want to track the event, for example in a layout file :

  ```
  <com.heysolutions.dentsply.Activites.MainActivity.TrackedClickButton
      xmlns:tracking="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      tracking:tracking_name="buttonTrackingName"/>
  ```

Once again, this is one way, may be some other easier/better/better with your implementation ways :)

Comment: thanks a lot..looks good..but is their any other way apart from this..as we have to integrate the analytics in large code base which is already developed, as this will require many changes..is there any other approach??

Comment: Hmm ok, regardless of how you implement the analytics call you always going to have a kind of mapping between the view that receive the input and the "trackingName" that you have to send… So it's kind of a dead end looking for no changes, except maybe with some kinda of configuration file that stores like view ids and trackingNames or so…

Comment: Would you mind telling us how you actually implemented it / what you've decided ?

Comment: Yaa we are still looking for best approach, final approach not decided yet..as there are some image buttons instead of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own clickListener in Kotlin.
In this exemple, I put a `debounceTime` variable to prevent double clicking :

```
fun View.clickAndTrack(debounceTime: Long = 500L, action: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        private var lastClickTime: Long = 0
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < debounceTime) return
            else {
                // do your Analytics action here
                action()
            }
            lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) to intercept touch events.